# How to get rid of the namespace error in xaml WP8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8.1 projet and i'm currently having issues using my BooleanToVisibility Converter.

[image: namespace]

Here is the Converter itself:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (!(value is bool))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        bool objValue = (bool)value;
        if (objValue)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my Xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="CityBox.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="using:CityBox.Views"
xmlns:converters="using:CityBox.Converters"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
x:Name="MyMainPage">

<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>


<Grid>
    <views:DataLoadingView x:Name="DataLoadingView" 
                           Visibility="{Binding LoadingViewVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <views:DrawerView  x:Name="DrawerView"  
                       Visibility="{Binding DrawerViewVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</Grid>
</Page>
```

And finaly my booleans from my ViewModel:

```
private bool _loadingViewVisibility;
    private bool _drawerViewVisibility;

    public bool LoadingViewVisibility
    {
        get { return _loadingViewVisibility;}
        set
        {
            _loadingViewVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingViewVisibility");
        }
    }
    public bool DrawerViewVisibility
    {
        get { return _drawerViewVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _drawerViewVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DrawerViewVisibility");
        }
    }
```

One thing that i don't understand and i think the problem might come from is that in the Resource (in the xaml), i have some kind of warning telling me that "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" is not in the specified namespace which is weird because it was automatically added by resharper. I thought it was just an error from VS like it happends sometimes but it doesn't work when i change the values of my bools.

Hope i was precise enough for you to help me!
thanks in advance,
Guillaume.

[image: xaml error]

EDIT : I just ran some tests and here is something interesting:

```
    <Grid>
    <!--<TextBlock Text="Test1" Visibility="{Binding Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Test2" Visibility="{Binding Test1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>-->
    <views:LoadingView Visibility="{Binding Test2, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <views:DrawerView Visibility="{Binding Test1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

If i uncomment the two textblocks and comment my two views then it works.
If i do it th other way arounds, it doesnt. in each of those views in simple put a Textblock saying "Loading" and "Drawer". in the case where i uncomment the two views and try to hide one by setting a bool to false, those two views are visible on the screen. Which doesn't happen if i do it with the two textboxes !!

Comment: change converters to Converters

Comment: I still have the same error even after that change

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml to:

```
<Page
x:Class="CityBox.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="using:CityBox.Views"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
x:Name="MyMainPage">

<Page.Resources>
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
<views:DataLoadingView x:Name="DataLoadingView" 
                       Visibility="{Binding LoadingViewVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<views:DrawerView  x:Name="DrawerView"  
                   Visibility="{Binding DrawerViewVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: If i don't put the "converter:" then i get a real error from visual studio at the static resource saying "Invalid resource: IValueConverter expected"

Comment: i dont have wp8. but in wpf if i put `xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CityBox.Converters"` and compile it the problem will gone.@bottus

Comment: Tried your solution and i end up with the same result than above, the real compile error

Comment: take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001635/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-for-library-project). the same problem. this is kind of bug. i fix it by recompiling or clean solution and recompile again.if it didnt work try the solution given in the link @bottus

Comment: i have no idea. so does this affect the warning? if so, i guess your problem is somewhere else. @bottus

Comment: It doesn't affect the warning, just the result. I just don't get it.. how can it work with the textblocks but not with the UserControls?!

Comment: so i guess you should ask a new question for the new problem :). but i dont know solution for that! @bottus